# Why does my android program look zoomed in on some devices?

Tags: android, zooming

Okay this is probably a newb question but I can't find any solutions on google.

I'm a new android programmer and I made a simple hello world type program. I didn't do any funny configurations in the layout xml file but for some reason on certain devices the screen looks really zoomed in and almost kinda pixelated.

Is there some kind of common reason for this? All I have on my linear layout is an EditText widget, a textview widget, and two button widgets.

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10px"
    >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtUser"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="200px"
      android:text="" />

<Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Submit"
      android:onClick="userSubmit" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Clear Screen"
      android:onClick="clearScreen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16px"
    android:text="Ready\n\n"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably some version of the [screen compatibility mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) which attempts to make old apps compatible with newer large displays, scaling the UI up as necessary. Scaling causes pixelated look as well.

If you don't specify a `targetSdkVersion` in your manifest, it defaults to 1, enabling all compatibility modes.

Solution: Specify an actual target SDK version you're developing your app on. Usually it should be the highest one available.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. The gui elements are prettier now too.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you should use DP `dp` units instead of Pixels `px` since DP works with the screen density. Remove things like `android:layout_width="200px"` and change them to `android:layout_width="200dp"`

**PS: note the following:**

Generally you do not want to set `dp` values, you should do pretty well using `wrap_content` or `match_parent`, since the `LinearLayout` calculate widths and heights for you. Try to resist the temptation of setting fixed values to views, unless is extremely necessary. As an experience Android developer I tell you that cases you wanna set fixed width/height are cases like:

1. You are downloading images from the Internet and you want the `ImageView` that will show it to be displayed as a placeholder until the download completes.
2. You're creating an horizontal gallery and you need to give it a maximum height so it wont surpass the screen.

In resume, complicated stuff like that. If you're starting, try to learn to use `wrap_content` and `match_parent`, it will save you a lot of headache later on :)